# UITableView scroll to row on different devices

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, viewdidload

I've came on some sort of bug (I guess)... In my `viewDidLoad:` after fetching and doing other stuff I scroll `UITableView` to the nearest date in future. I use for this my method but basicaly it becomes to call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`. Everything is working good as I call this method from a button action or after `UITableView` is reloaded but...

When I run thsis app on iPhone 4S (real device) it doesn't scroll me to this row in `viewDidLoad` but lists me that this method was executed properly! What is more, when I run this in simulator (5 or 5S) everything works like charm! This code doesn't even work when I run this in iPhone 4 simulator... Why? Was there some sort of chanange which need to determine what kinde of device am I using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to have a look at two options:

1) Instead of `viewDidLoad` you should move your scrolling logic to `viewDidAppear` or `after some delay`

2) Handle this delegate and once the desired cell loaded scroll to its position:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0)
{
    if(indexPath.row == someFutureDateRowNumber)
    {
          // TODO : do scrolling here.
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` after delay. You may use `- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;`